# Transferring data from Excel to TestStand and then to LabVIEW

Tags: labview, teststand

I have presently created a small project in LabVIEW to understand the usage and communication between LabVIEW and TestStand. The VI has 8 switches and 8 lights. Is it possible for me to create an Excel file from which the TestStand will read and send these I/O parameters to LabVIEW in order to operate those switches?
I am very new to TestStand but I use LabVIEW a lot in day to day life. So any help is appreciated.

I would also like to know how the Excel file should look like.

Comment: TestStand usually runs VIs, not the other way around. You can export a CSV from Teststand and read it in LabVIEW without Excel. The structure of the CSV is up to you.

Comment: Labview will be run by TestStand. But I want to send the values from TestStand to Labview from an Excel sheet because for my future work I will receive all the data in Excel format, which is to be used in Labview. I want to send that data to Labview using TestStand.
Like for example I want to turn the first switch on, which is basically in BOOL. So 'T' must be read from an Excelsheet by TestStand and inturn turn first switch on in LabVIEW. Now I am preparing myself for later.

Comment: That's an XY problem. Break your system into smaller  pieces, then we can help.

Comment: From LV to Excel - use the RTG or the Excel .NET API. From Teststand to Excel, you will have to write a plugin. From Teststand to LV - use the Teststand LV API.

Comment: Okay, to break it down, Can I control a labVIEW program, for example change a BOOL value, thorugh TestStand (where I get these BOOL values from an Excel sheet.)?

Comment: Yes, use an action that calls the VI with this BOOL value.

Comment: Thank you. That helped! :)
One last thing, Can I change input values in labview(e.g. BOOL inputs) using TestStand without connecting the inputs to connectorpane in Labview?

Comment: You are asking for dry water..

Comment: I just need an yes/no answer. That's all I asked. There is no need to  be passive aggressive.  Anyway, I will continue with my research and try some things out.

Comment: You pass data to a VI via the connector pane. You asked how do it without connecting to the connector pane, that's generally not possible.

Comment: I am trying to figure out a way because there are too many inputs, more than a connector pane can hold. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: You can use arrays, clusters or reference to Teststand internal API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have finally figured out how it works. To get the format of the excel file, I exported the properties into an excel file( the ones I want to change in Labview). I created fileglobals and exported it to get an example of Excel sheet. I inturn used this Excel file to change the values of Fileglobals or even add more of fileglobals or parameters.

Then I defined the inputs of the Labview using connectorpane, I connected all the inputs and outputs in labview to a cluster. I can do it in this Program but I am yet to figure out how to do it when I have a lot of inputs and a lot of outputs. If I use clusters everywhere, the CPU usage increases and it's not very efficient to use clusters everywhere. Because I work with labview programs where there are over 150 inputs and outputs. So clusters are not very feasible. But for smaller amount of Inputs/Outputs, it works well.

Then I used result processing to send the input/output to a database which I created using microsoft SQL server studio 18 and edited the tables using database viewer which comes along with TestStand. And then exported this data into an excel sheet.

Works perfectly fine.

Presently on to the next step where in I wanna write input output as well into excel. My present Program writes only Pass/fail or numeric limits in excel. On to the next step now. Will write here when I figure that out as well :)